# How te get an element from .fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach, multer

I am having trouble getting the property filename from the `req.files` that I get from the router. Here's what I get:

[image: Image of the result of requiring req.files]

And here's how I've been trying to get the filename of each (I am only using 2 pictures in this example but I could get more than two images so that's why I am iterating with the forEach)

```
let arrayImages = [];

if (req.files) {                                                      
  Array(req.files).forEach(image => {
    arrayImages.push(image[0].filename);
  })
}
```

Comment: As per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of your code (or data, either). Code is text. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please edit your question to include the code as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks

Comment: Anyway it's unclear what the problem is exactly...you say you're "having trouble" but don't explain specifically what the trouble is. You show us some code which just pushes the list of files into an array. Where are you stuck? Have you made any attempt to read the filename property? In your loop, it looks like `image[0].filename` ought to contain it.

Comment: I'm sorry the trouble that i am having is that i cant get the filename. I've tried with image[0].filename and other variants and either way i can't seem to get it. And when i console.log the array 'arrayImages' after i supposedly pushed the elements of the req.files inside it it's like if i get the whole req.files again. I am new to programming so if the question sounds silly or it seems that i haven`t gave it too much thought i am sorry. Been stuck since yesterday with this same problem

Comment: `it's like if i get the whole req.files again` well yes because you basically just copied it item by item

Comment: `can't seem to get it.` ...well what _exactly_ happens when you use `image[0].filename` then? An error? Other unexpected result? Please be clear and specific about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hi everyone thanks for all the help, i finally figured it out!

```
let arrayImages = [];
for (const clave in req.files) {
    array = req.files[clave]
    arrayImages.push(`${array[0].filename}`);
}
```

that way i've got the fieldname of each element

Answer (score 0):

The root of your data from screen is an object.

So try to code like that:

```js
let arrayImages = [];

if (req.files) {                                                      
  Object.values(req.files).forEach(arr => {
    arrayImages.push(arr[0].filename);
  })
}
```